# Adding filter to SVG image inside another SVG image

Tags: html, css, svg, css-filters

I have following markup:

```
<svg>
  <img src="path/to/another/image.svg" />
</svg>
```

Applying filter to `img` seems that doesn't work. Any solution?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you wrapping a HTML img tag within a svg element??

Comment: If you intend to use an image inside an svg element use `<image xlink:href....` instead of  `<img src="...`

Answer (score 5):

> Why are you wrapping a HTML img tag within a svg element?? – Michael
>   Mullany

HTML tag `<img>` needs to be rendered out from svg. Only filter definition should remain inside svg.

Below is an example of using a separate `SVG` file uploaded to a server, which is added to HTML markup using the`<img>`tag

The filter is applied to the file svg `<feFlood flood-color =" #35B62E"/>` for coloring in green color

I used `<feOffset dy =" 150 ">` to partially paint over the shape.

```css
img {
filter:url(#filter1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Face.svg" width="371" height="348" >

<svg  version="1.1" width="371" height="348" viewBox="0 0 371 348" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
 <filter id="filter1" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#35B62E" />
      <feOffset  dy="150">
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter>
   </defs>
 
</svg>
```

Below is an example using two `<feFlood flood-color` filters to get a color change when you hover the cursor

```css
img {
filter:url(#filter_G);
}

img:hover {
filter:url(#filter_R);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://svg-art.ru/files/Face.svg" width="371" height="348" >

<svg  version="1.1" width="371" height="348" viewBox="0 0 371 348" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
 <filter id="filter_G" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="#35B62E" />
      <feOffset  dy="150">
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter> 
 
  <filter id="filter_R" x="0%" y="0%">
      <feFlood flood-color="red" />
      <feOffset  dy="65">
      </feOffset>
      <feComposite operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic" />
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic" />
    </filter> 
   </defs>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: @Nerver Corameiro If the solution was useful to you, please mark it as a solution